# Is $(\tan x)(\sin x)^3 + 3\cos x - \cos 3x = \sec x + \cos x$?

Tags: calculus

Is $(\tan x)(\sin x)^3 + 3\cos x - \cos 3x = \sec x + \cos x$?

I integrated $(\sec x)^2(\sin x)^3$ by parts, it gave me a pretty messy answer and I’m trying to prove that it’s equal to the same as if I integrated using mostly trig instead to get it to a simpler form I can integrate. I need help manipulating the left side of the equation so that it’s equal to the right, can anybody help?

Comment: Try substituting $\pi/3$ for $x$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: we get
$$\tan(x)\sin(x)^3+2\cos(x)-\cos(3x)-\sec(x)=3\cos(x)\sin(x)^2$$

Comment: I’ve tried changing the tan to sin/cos and distributing the cos x to all the terms, only managed to get to -3cosx^3 + 4cosx + secx.

Comment: One Moment please, i will have a look at my paper sheet

Comment: $$\tan(x)\sin(x)^3+2\cos(x)-\cos(3x)=\tan(x)\sin(x)^3+5\cos(x)-4\cos(x)^3$$

Comment: and $$\tan(x)\sin(x)^3+5\cos(x)-4\cos(x)^3-\sec(x)=3\cos(x)\sin(x)^2$$